# Múltiples consultas dentro de foreach Laravel 5

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, foreach

No logro dar con la solución espero alguien me pueda ayudar. Tengo una consulta:

```
$perdidasyganancias = Perdidas_Ganancias::all();
```

La cual me retorna 6 filas. Pero en cada una de esas filas tiene un código diferente que luego necesito hacer una consulta a una `view` en mi base de datos. Para realizar entonces las consultas según el numero de registro que me retorne la primera consulta he creado un `foreach` y le pongo la consulta dentro del `foreach`, pero no me funciona. Entonces convertí a `sql` esas consultas para ver cual era el `sql` que me genera utilizando en vez del `get()`, el `toSql()`, y pude ver que en lugar de el valor de la variable me esta poniendo un signo `?` la cuál indica que no hay un valor, pero si el valor está correctamente puesto. ¿Cómo hago las múltiples consultas dentro del `foreach`?

```
$perdidasyganancias = Perdidas_Ganancias::all();
    $year = $carbon->now()->format('Y');
    $obtener_resultados = [];

        foreach ($perdidasyganancias as $data) {
        $cod_cuenta = $data->cod_cuenta;
        $cuenta = $data->cuenta;

            $obtener_resultados[] = Agrupacion_sumada::OrderBy('cod_cuenta','ASC')
            ->where('cod_cuenta',$cod_cuenta)->where('cuenta',$cuenta)->Where('periodo','=',$year)->toSql();
        }
        dd($obtener_resultados);
```

lo que me retorna es

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => "select * from `sumas_agrupadas` where `cod_cuenta` = ? and `cuenta` = ? and `periodo` = ? order by `cod_cuenta` asc"
  1 => "select * from `sumas_agrupadas` where `cod_cuenta` = ? and `cuenta` = ? and `periodo` = ? order by `cod_cuenta` asc"
  2 => "select * from `sumas_agrupadas` where `cod_cuenta` = ? and `cuenta` = ? and `periodo` = ? order by `cod_cuenta` asc"
  3 => "select * from `sumas_agrupadas` where `cod_cuenta` = ? and `cuenta` = ? and `periodo` = ? order by `cod_cuenta` asc"
  4 => "select * from `sumas_agrupadas` where `cod_cuenta` = ? and `cuenta` = ? and `periodo` = ? order by `cod_cuenta` asc"
  5 => "select * from `sumas_agrupadas` where `cod_cuenta` = ? and `cuenta` = ? and `periodo` = ? order by `cod_cuenta` asc"
]
```

OJO las tabla no están relacionadas.

Comment: Es correcto el `?` en la consulta, revisa como funciona PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Mirate lo siguiente: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Pero las tablas no están relacionadas, la segunda consulta es un view en mi DB no me serviria relacionarlas con eloquent

Comment: No entiendo la necesidad de hacer todo eso en un foreach, si con relaciones laravel te entrega los datos de una forma tan comoda para su acceso

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que Agrupacion_sumada es un modelo, en ese caso yo haria algo así, no tengo forma de testear el código, pero mi experiencia me dice que debería de funcionar

```
$year = $carbon->now()->format('Y');

$perdidasyganancias = Perdidas_Ganancias::pluck('cod_cuenta', 'cuenta');

$collection = $perdidasyganancias->each(function ($cod_cuenta, $cuenta) {
    return Agrupacion_sumada::OrderBy('cod_cuenta','ASC')
                            ->where('cod_cuenta',$cod_cuenta)
                            ->where('cuenta',$cuenta)
                            ->Where('periodo',$year)
                            ->get();
});

dd($collection);
```